# Why does my OS stagnate after calling this function on Linux, but works on Windows?

Tags: c, x86, operating-system, osdev, bochs

I'm writing a basic operating system - I've written the boot sector and switched the CPU to 32-bit protected mode, enabling me to write the code in C rather than assembly. In C, I've written a basic screen driver and have successfully loaded the kernel (by that I mean, the code within the `kernel.c` file begins to be executed).

**The problem arises when the `terminal_initialise()` function is called.** Its purpose is to set the background colour and position the cursor at 0, 0. As you can see from the screenshot of Bochs, it runs successfully - finishing the loop and setting the cursor position. **The issue is that no code after that function call in `kernel.c` gets executed.** **Any ideas why?**

*Apologies for the lack of error messages, but they're not possible at this stage. I've got a few compiler warnings for implicit function declarations, but that's it.*

**Update:**
It seems that the code runs perfectly fine on Windows in both QEMU and Bochs, but fails to run on Linux on both. I'm working on finding out why, but I can't see the solution. My main development environment is Linux, so this is still vital to me, but not quite as critical.

**screen.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE
#define HEADER_FILE

#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000
#define MAX_ROWS 25
#define MAX_COLS 80
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK 0x0f

#define REG_SCREEN_CTRL 0x3D4
#define REG_SCREEN_DATA 0x3D5

/* VARIABLES AND ENUMS */

enum colour {
    COLOUR_BLACK = 0,
    COLOUR_BLUE = 1,
    COLOUR_GREEN = 2,
    COLOUR_CYAN = 3,
    COLOUR_RED = 4,
    COLOUR_MAGENTA = 5,
    COLOUR_BROWN = 6,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    COLOUR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    COLOUR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    COLOUR_WHITE = 15,
};

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */

char generate_attribute_byte(enum colour, enum colour);
int get_screen_offset(int, int);
void print_char(char, int, int, char);
void print_at(char*, int, int, char);
void print(char*, char);
void set_cursor(int);
int get_cursor();
void clear_screen();
int handle_scrolling(int);

#endif
```

**screen.c:**

```
#include "screen.h"

/* FUNCTIONS */

char generate_attribute_byte(enum colour fg, enum colour bg) {
    return fg | bg << 4;
}

/* ---------- PRINTING FUNCTIONS ----------*/

void print_char(char character, int col, int row, char attribute_byte) {
    unsigned char *vidmem = (unsigned char *) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    if (!attribute_byte) {
        attribute_byte = generate_attribute_byte(COLOUR_WHITE, COLOUR_BLACK);
    }

    int offset;
    if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) {
        offset = get_screen_offset(col, row);
    } else {
        offset = get_cursor();
    }

    if (character == '\n') {
        int rows = offset / (2 * MAX_COLS);
        offset =  get_screen_offset(79, rows);
    } else {
        vidmem[offset] = character;
        vidmem[offset + 1] = attribute_byte;
    }

    offset += 2;
    offset = handle_scrolling(offset);
    set_cursor(offset);
}

void print_at(char* message, int col, int row, char attribute_byte) {
    if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) {
        set_cursor(get_screen_offset(col, row));
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(message[i] != 0) {
        print_char(message[i++], col, row, attribute_byte);
    }
}

void print(char* message, char attribute_byte) {
    print_at(message, -1, -1, attribute_byte);
}

/* ---------- OFFSET AND CURSOR CALCULATIONS ----------*/

int get_screen_offset(int col, int row) {
    return ((row * MAX_COLS) + col) * 2;
}

void set_cursor(int offset) {
    offset /= 2;
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 14);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset >> 8));
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 15);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset & 0xff));
}

int get_cursor() {
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 14);
    int offset = port_byte_in(REG_SCREEN_DATA) << 8;
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 15);
    offset += port_byte_in(REG_SCREEN_DATA);
    return offset * 2;
}

/* ---------- MISC ----------*/

void clear_screen() {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < MAX_COLS; col++) {
            print_char(' ', col, row, WHITE_ON_BLACK);
        }
    }

    set_cursor(get_screen_offset(0, 0));
}

int handle_scrolling(int cursor_offset) {
    if (cursor_offset < MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLS * 2) {
        return cursor_offset;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        memory_copy(get_screen_offset(0, i) + VIDEO_ADDRESS,
                    get_screen_offset(0, i - i) + VIDEO_ADDRESS,
                    MAX_COLS * 2);
    }

    char* last_line = get_screen_offset(0, MAX_ROWS - 1) + VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_COLS * 2; i++) {
        last_line[i] = 0;
    }

    cursor_offset -= 2 * MAX_COLS;

    return cursor_offset;
}
```

**kernel.h:**

```
#include "../drivers/screen.h"

/* VARIABLES AND ENUMS */

unsigned char terminal_colour;
unsigned short terminal_buffer;

/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */

void terminal_initialise();
char get_scan_code();
char get_char();

/* FUNCTIONS */

void terminal_initialise() {
    terminal_colour = generate_attribute_byte(COLOUR_WHITE, COLOUR_LIGHT_GREEN);
    terminal_buffer = VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    for (char row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++) {
        for (char col = 0; col < MAX_COLS; col++) {
            print_char(' ', col, row, terminal_colour);
        }
    }
    set_cursor(get_screen_offset(0, 0));
}


unsigned char scancode[128] =
{
    0, 27, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=',
    '\b', /* Backspace */
    '\t', /* Tab */
    'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '[', ']', '\n',    /* Enter key */
    0,    /* Control */
    'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';',
    '\'',
    '`',
    0,    /* Left shift */
    '\\', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n',
    'm', ',', '.', '/',
    0,    /* Right shift */
    '*',
    0,    /* Alt */
    ' ',   /* Space bar */
    0,    /* Caps lock */
    0,    /* F1 key ... > */
    0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
    0,    /* < ... F10 */
    0,    /* 69 - Num lock*/
    0,    /* Scroll Lock */
    0,    /* Home key */
    0,    /* Up Arrow */
    0,    /* Page Up */
    '-',
    0,    /* Left Arrow */
    0,
    0,    /* Right Arrow */
    '+',
    0,    /* 79 - End key*/
    0,    /* Down Arrow */
    0,    /* Page Down */
    0,    /* Insert Key */
    0,    /* Delete Key */
    0,   0,   0,
    0,    /* F11 Key */
    0,    /* F12 Key */
    0,    /* All other keys are undefined */
};

char get_scan_code() {
    char c = 0;
    do {
        if (port_byte_in(0x60) != c) {
            c = port_byte_in(0x60);
            if (c > 0) {
                return c;
            }
        }
    } while(1);
}

char get_char() {
    return scancode[get_scan_code()+1];
}
```

**kernel.c:**

```
#include "kernel.h"

void _start() {
    terminal_initialise();
    // NO EXECUTION AFTER THIS POINT
    print((char[]){"OS v1.0.0\n"}, generate_attribute_byte(COLOUR_WHITE, COLOUR_LIGHT_GREEN));
    prompt();
}
```

**Makefile:**

```
C_SOURCES = $(wildcard kernel/*.c drivers/*.c)
HEADERS = $(wildcard kernel/*.h drivers/*.h)

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}

all: os-image

os-image: boot/boot_sect.bin kernel.bin
    cat $^ > os-image

kernel.bin: kernel.tmp
    objcopy -O binary -j .text $< $@

kernel.tmp: kernel/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
    ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^

%.o : %.c ${HEADERS}
    gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.asm
    nasm $< -f elf -o $@

%.bin : %.asm
    nasm $< -f bin -I '../../16bit/' -o $@
```

[Bochs Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTJAI.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242203/discussion-on-question-by-brandonoconnell-why-does-my-os-stagnate-after-calling).

Comment: *I've got a few compiler warnings for implicit function declarations*: Those are potentially lethal - if the compiler doesn't know what argument types the function expects, it may pass them in a way that doesn't work.  Fix those before proceeding.

Comment: And by the way, `int get_cursor();` doesn't mean "no arguments" in C, it means "unspecified arguments".  If you pass arguments anyway, the compiler won't stop you, and the resulting code may misbehave.  It should be `int get_cursor(void);`.

Comment: One thing I'd worry about is that your Windows / Linux compilers may be using Windows / Linux calling conventions respectively.  They are different and incompatible, and this is a problem because when C calls assembly or vice versa, the assembly has to conform to what the C code expects.  I'm not sure offhand if that could cause your problem, but it's something to check.